# REACT_NATIVE - Handle DeepLink from automatic side-service redirection web URL's

Tags: android, ios, react-native, deep-linking, branch.io

I have this use case :

-> a Website **OR** random native application on my phone, doing a process on it, and at the end of the flow, this application is redirecting to :

`https://my-domain/com/key=value&otherKey=value.com`

The problem is, the universal link is well handled (deep links works well) if I click on it (through bloc-note or whatever) and it's opening my mobile app. But for this use case, since it's not a user's click but an automatic redirection (from the side-service application), it's opening safari and not my app...

How can I handle that?

Branch.io looks not enough, since it's not a static url. Foreach redirected URL you indeed have a different `key/value` in the url

Answer (score 2):

What you are experiencing is expected behavior when using Universal Links. In your question, you mention "But for this use case, since it's not a user's click but an automatic redirection". Universal links need the end-user to physically click on the link and there can be no redirection. The main purpose of Universal Links was to prevent the end-user from being automatically redirected without their knowledge and consent. By clicking on the link, the end-user is essentially giving their consent and intention. The only workaround to this is to not use Universal Links. This is a core functionality of the Universal Links and was put in place by Apple to prevent the function you are trying to do. There is no workaround.

Comment: Alright, I understand, is there any way to handle it ? I mean I can send a custom callback url if the user is on mobile like `myapp://` but if the user doesn't have the application, it's not gonna works too...

Answer (score 0):

> Some example cases where Chrome does not launch an external
>   application are as follows:
>
> - The intent could not be resolved, i.e., no app can handle the intent.
> - JavaScript timer tried to open an application without user gesture.

And

> Chrome doesn’t launch an external app for a given Intent URI in the
>   following cases.
>
> - When the Intent URI is redirected from a typed in URL.
> - When the Intent URI is initiated without user gesture.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents#see-also